# how to show null row value when value not exist in query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, null

I want to show all records of examresult on basis of `category_id`.
Every subject has 2 category IDs. How to show result when one `category_id` of examresult is not present in the result?
I want to show `null` on some column and some value when the `category_id` exists.
This image will give you a clear view of what I want to ask.
Thanks in advance.

```sql
select er.subject_id,er.student_id,er.class_id,
 ec.exam_catagory_name,er.catagory_id, er.exam_type_id, sum( er.marks_obtained) subject_marks_obtained, sum(er.total_marks) subject_total_marks from Exam_Results er
join Exam_Subjects es on er.subject_id=es.subject_id
join Exam_Catagories ec on ec.exam_catagory_id=er.catagory_id
where er.student_id=2369 and er.session_id=81 and er.class_id=265
 and er.subclass_id=182 and er.term_id=148 and er.shift_id=35 
group by er.student_id,er.subject_id,er.class_id,er.catagory_id,er.exam_type_id
,er.term_id,ec.exam_catagory_name
 order by er.subject_id
```

**Output:**

[image: Output Result Image]

There are 20 records, but I want 27 records with both examination and assessment with `null` values in marks. How to show examination and assessment record of `subject_id` and give `null` in marks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I see you don't have this additional row in `Exam_Results ` table, right?

Comment: I suspect that you could illustrate the problem with a far simpler query.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: yes right, some other subject id also not have categoryid =51 as seen in the image. how to show it null in additional row.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use `case` statement:

```
case when category_id = 51 then null else subject_marks_obtained end [subject_marks_obtained],
case when category_id = 51 then null else subject_total_marks end [subject_total_marks]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
join Exam_Catagories ec on ec.exam_catagory_id=er.catagory_id
```

Instead of above part  of  your  query , Please  try  with  following script part.

```
left join Exam_Catagories   ec on ec.exam_catagory_id=er.catagory_id and ec.exam_catagory_id in (51,52)
```

Comment: still same records output come. nothing happen on the output .

Answer (score 0):

using left join at Exam_Catagories , so record at Exam_Results will show up even not match with exam category id

Comment: still same records output come. nothing happen on the output .